# Find difference between two exploded comma-separated strings

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, array-difference

I've read some tutorials on here but none of them return what I need. I have two arrays.

```
$a = '5,6,'; 
$b = '6,6,'; 
$a_array = explode(',',$a); 
$b_array = explode(',',$b);
$result = array_diff($b_array,$a_array); 
var_dump($result);
```

However, when I run array_diff, it returns an empty array.

```
$result = array_diff($b_array,$a_array);
```

But I'd like it to return 6. What's the error in my code?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are comparing the b to the a. The b array contains no elements that are different from elements in a. All the similar elements are not compared to elements in similar positions. They are compared to all elements from the opposite array. If you compared a to b, you would return the 5 value in the result array, because no elements in b have 5. But when you compare b to a, each 6 finds a pair in a, so no differences are found.

```
$a = '5,6,'; 
$b = '6,6,'; 
$a_array = explode(',',$a); 
$b_array = explode(',',$b);
$result = array_diff($a_array,$b_array); 
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thank @bronkula  But $b = '7,6,';   returns 7 , why ?

Comment: If a has not changed, 7 will not be present in it. '5,6,' compared to '6,6,' will find a difference. '6,6,' compared to '5,6,' will not. '7,6,' will find a difference from '5,6,'

Answer (score 0):

array_diff() doesn't work like this.

array_diff($b_array,$a_array) would return an array with entries that are present in $b_array but not present in $a_array.

So, in your case, it would check if $a_array contains '6' or not two times( as $b_array would be having two '6') and will found out each time that yes, $a_array contains'6' and hence returns empty array.

For more insights: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff.asp

Comment: Thank @Ayush Jain : But $b = '7,6,'; returns 7 , why ?

Comment: Yes Kelvin, it should return 7.

Comment: Actually, if $b= '7,6' and $a = '5,6' and you do array_diff($b_array,$a_array), then what it would do is, it would check if '7' is present in $a or not, as '7' is not present in $a, it would add '7' to final result.

Comment: and finally, it would check if '6' is present in $a or not, as '6' is already there in $a, it won't add it to the result and hence you get '7' as final output.

Comment: If it is still not clear, we can workout with different examples if you like

Comment: Welcome Kelvin, feel free to upvote my answer as a token of appreciation if I have cleared your doubt.